# Android Gradle project sync failed due to unresolved dependency

Tags: android, build.gradle

I recently added a card-stack-view dependency (implementation 'com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:2.3.4') to my app level build.gradle and after that my project is giving syncing failure like:-

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx
>   
>   Affected Modules: app

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.animeapp.brijender.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:run ner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:2.3.4'
}
```

Can anyone help what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: If you are not working behind a proxy can you please run `./gradlew app:assembleDebug --info` to find out what is happening? Please update the results you will get in the question as well!

Comment: I am not able to see see all of the command output in android studio terminal. It is not showing all of the output.

Comment: @denis_lor No worries got it. Just Needed to remove these dependencies

`androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:run ner:1.2.0'`
`androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'`

Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Just add jCenter repository in project’s build.gradle (or if you are using the new way just add it in your settings.gradle)

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

include ':app'

Answer (score 0):

Just Needed to remove these dependencies androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:run ner:1.2.0' androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'